# How to specify a lifetime when borrowing a new object instance?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'd like to fill a `Vec<Foo>` with `Foo`s instanced within the `fill` function scope. Is this even possible with rust? I tried playing with lifetimes but I can't project what I learnt from tutorials/documentation/samples on this specific use-case.

```rust
pub struct Foo {
    pub integer: Box<u32>,
}

pub fn fill1(mut vec: Vec<&Foo>) {
    // Error: argument requires that borrow lasts for `'1`
    vec.push(&Foo { integer: Box::new(1) });
}

pub fn fill2<'a>(mut vec: Vec<&'a Foo>) {
    // Error: argument requires that borrow lasts for `'a`
    vec.push(&Foo { integer: Box::new(1) });
}
```

If this makes no sense (I'd be happy to understand why), I was thinking of modifying method signature for `pub fn fill3(mut vec: Vec<Foo>, foos: Foos)` (no borrowing). I have however a bunch of other problems if I do so.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=614e1ffd3f324f3d64c7e305a7a3b56f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot work, because you are pushing references to local variables, which will be destroyed when the method finishes. This can be seen easier if you rewrite the method like this:

```rust
pub fn fill1(mut vec: Vec<&Foo>) {
    // a local variable - exists only within the stack frame of the method
    let foo = Foo { integer: Box::new(1) };

    // `&foo` will be a dangling reference after the method exits
    vec.push(&foo);

} // foo is destroyed here, but `vec` still exists, containing pointers to freed memory, or memory used by some other function
```

> But in this case, why would this work? `fn fill(mut vec: Vec<Foo>, foos: Foos)`

It will *kind of* work, but at the end of the method your whole vector would be dropped (dealloccated), so this version of `fill()` is not ok either. Instead you should accept a reference to a mutable vector, meaning that someone else owns the vector, but it gives you a temporary access to modify it:

```rust
// vec is a mutable reference, thus the vector's
// life is not tied with the function execution
// i.e. it will still exist after the function executes
pub fn fill_ok(vec: &mut Vec<Foo>) { 
    let foo = Foo {
        integer: Box::new(1),
    };

    // `foo` is copied to the vector, which is 
    // backed by a heap allocation. The local 
    // variable `foo` will still be destroyed, 
    // but the copy in the heap (the vec) will
    // remain
    vec.push(foo); 
}
```

> My usecase is indeed a little more complex. Passing a reference to a mutable vector fixes the first part of the problem, but then things are still tricky to me if I want to be able to add both objects owned from the outside and from the function scope

In that case you can use `Cow` as @Peter Hall suggested. It has to variants - one that holds a reference, and one that holds an owned value.

The downside is that your object has to implement the `Clone` trait. If that's not an option, you can easily roll out your own `Cow` without that requirement

```rust
#[derive(Clone)] // Objects must implement `Clone` in order to be used with `Cow`
pub struct Foo {
    pub integer: Box<u32>,
}

pub fn fill2<'a>(vec: &'a mut Vec<Cow<'a, Foo>>, foos: &'a Foos) {
    vec.push(Cow::Owned(Foo {
        integer: Box::new(1),
    }));

    for foo in &foos.foos {
        vec.push(Cow::Borrowed(foo));
    }
}
```

Comment: Mhh makes sense. But in this case, why would this work?
`fn fill(mut vec: Vec<Foo>, foos: Foos) { vec.push(Foo { integer: Box::new(1) }); }`

Comment: In that case you are pushing a an `owned` value, not a reference. Thus the memory is not freed/reused after the method end

Comment: @OlivierGiniaux if you have need for the `Vec` to hold references, but also be able to insert owned values, then you might want to change it to `Vec<Rc<Foo>>` or `Vec<Cow<Foo>>` instead. Really depends on your real use-case.

Comment: Yeah, but `Cow<Foo>` still won't allow for references to local variables. The core issue here is that OP needs to understand the idea of ownership. i.e. someone, somewhere has to `own` the value

Comment: You would use a `Cow::Owned` for those. That's the point.

Comment: My usecase is indeed a little more complex. Passing a reference to a mutable vector fixes the first part of the problem, but then things are still tricky to me if I want to be able to add both objects owned from the outside and from the function scope. See this [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0515c3fd134e6bb10c008b65ae13e65c). Will read about `Rc<T>` and `Cow<T>`, maybe this is what I need!

Comment: @OlivierGiniaux in that case `Cow` is the way to go as @Peter Hall suggested